# When do I use "s'efforcer à" vs "s'efforcer de"?

Tags: prépositions

The WordReference page for ["s'efforcer"](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/efforcer) has these two entries (among other entries):

- s'efforcer **de** faire [qch]
- s'efforcer **à** faire [qch]

The English translations for each of these entries are identical!

---

I notice that the [TLFi page](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/efforcer) for "efforcer" has the following two entires (among others) *(the English translation below is from my own attempt at understanding the entry)*:

- A: Followed by a complement

  - 1: The complement is an Infinitive

    - a) S'efforcer à + [Infinitive]
    - b) S'efforcer de + [Infinitive]
  - 2: The complement is a "Substantif" (= "noun phrase"?)

    - a) S'efforcer vers + [Substantif]
    - b) S'efforcer à + [Substantif]

So I suppose this is saying that you cannot use "S'efforcer de + substantif". But it seems that both *à* and *de* can be used if the complement is an Infinitive, but the TLFi doesn't seem to tell me which I should choose to use, in what circumstances.

---

Questions:

1. When should I use *de*, vs *à* after "s'efforcer"?
2. Can you help me see how the [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99efforcer) page, the [TLFi page](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/efforcer), or some other internet resource, could have told me the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use ***de***. The other prepositions are very rare and literary.

A simple way to compare the various forms is to use Google NGrams to see [what word usually follows *s'efforcer*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%27efforce%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3):

[image]

Here, it's obviously ***de*** or it's shortened form ***d'*** while ***à*** is far behind and the remaining ones are almost zero.

You can then figure out what most follows ***s'efforcer de*** [this way](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%27efforcer%20de%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3):

[image]

Here, only verbs or pronouns are reported so the TLFi *sustantifs* are also very rare.

NGrams being based on printed material, it might underevaluate expressions more prevalent in spoken than in written French, but its figures are generally accurate.

I never use *s'efforcer à* but my feeling is that *il s'efforce à xxx* is stronger and imply some struggle to achieve the goal of doing xxx while *il s'efforce de xxx* might just mean doing xxx is prioritized against something else.

Finally, here is an excerpt from the *[Nouveau dictionnaire de la langue française](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50750g/f686.image.r=efforce%20a#)*, Second edition,  from Jean-Charles Laveaux.

It is not exactly new (1828) but it discusses the difference between ***s'efforcer à*** and ***s'efforcer de*** with some points that seem to me still relevant.

> **S'EFFORCER.** verbe pronominal. Faire des efforts
> pour venir à bout de quelque chose. *S'efforcer
>
> de soulever un fardeau. S'efforcer de vaincre.
>
> S'efforcer de plaire. Il aimait les louanges et il
>
> est à souhaiter qu'un roi les aime, parce qu'a-
>
> lors il s'efforce de les mériter.* (Volt.) *La natu-
>
> re s'y efforce de faire du bien aux homme.
>
> mais les hommes n'y ont pas secondé la nature.*
> (Idem.)
>
> Ce verbe régit tantôt la préposition *à*, tan-
> tôt la préposition *de*. Lorsque les efforts ten-
> dent faire une action déterminée dont le
> sujet du verbe est l'agent immédiat, il faut
> employer la préposition *à*, parce que le sujet
> par ses efforts tend vers un but qu'il veut at-
> teindre, et que la préposition *à* marque cette
> tendance. *Il s'efforce à crier, à parler, à mar-
>
> cher*. Mais si l'action est indéterminée, on
> emploiera *de*, parce que *à* suppose toujours
> un point fixe et déterminé. *Il s'efforce d'agir,
>
> s'efforce de parvenir, il s'efforce de paraître
>
> indifférent.* Il en est de même si le sujet du
> verbe n'est pas l'agent immédiat de la totalité
> de l'action à laquelle tendent les efforts. Alors
> *de* est la seule préposition que l'on puisse em-
> ployer, parce que *à*, indiquant le but des ef-
> forts, annoncerait le sujet comme l'agent im-
> médiat de l'action totale. Quand je dis, *je
>
> m'efforce à crier*, *à* indique que c'est moi qui
> dois faire immédiatement l'action indiquée par
> le verbe qui doit suivre, c'est-à-dire, l'action
> de crier. Mais si je disais, *je m'efforce à ga-
> rder votre amitié, *à* annoncerait que je suis
> l'agent immédiat de la totalité de l'action qui
> va être indiquée, tandis que je n'en suis en
> effet que la cause occasionnelle. Je n'efforce
> non à faire une action déterminée, mais à
> attirer sur moi un effet déterminé qui dépend
> de tous, savoir, votre amitié. Il faut donc
> dire *je m'efforce de gagner votre amitié, d'ob-
>
> tenir la faveur du prince, le suffrage du public*
> et non pas *je m'efforce à gagner votre amitié,
>
> à obtenir la faveur du prince, le suffrage du pu-
>
> blic.* On dire de même qu'*un homme s'ef-
>
> force d'être plaisant, d'être gai; qu'une femme
>
> s'efforce de plaire, etc.*

Comment: so, it looks like dictionaries aren't meant to give me this information then, i suppose? if i understand you correctly, when *à* ends up being used with *s'efforcer*, it has the same meaning as if *de* was used instead? or is there a subtle nuance difference between *s'efforcer à + inf* and *s'efforcer de + inf* ?

Comment: At least the TLFi is giving popularity figures, but that's only for single words. I never use *s'efforcer à* but my feeling is that *il s'efforce à xxx* is stronger and imply some struggle to achieve the goal of doing xxx while *il s'efforce de xxx* might just mean doing xxx is prioritized against something else.

Comment: (i read 70% of the extract, with about a 80% comprehension by using your comment as a clue). i wonder if the distinction between *à* and *de*, when used with *s'efforcer*, can be generalized with other verbs? that is, that *à* indicates acting with a more direct, total, pointed goal, and where the subject is the total agent that makes the goal happen, and *de* is used when the subject isn't the total agent, or the goal isn't as direct?

Comment: at any rate, would you be willing to put your comment into your answer? your (English) comment was very helpful for me to (try to) read through that extract.

Comment: It's difficult to generalize this difference. With many verbs, there is no choice. You just use the required preposition. When both are possible, the meaning might be very different (*je pars de la maison* = from vs *je pars à la maison* = to ), sometimes, the difference is the register (*je commence à travailler*, standard, and *je commence de travailler* formal).

Comment: i can't help but wonder, "*why* might *je commence à travailler* sound less formal? is it merely 'that's the way it is', or is there some actual reason (eg, maybe because  *de* is *in general* more formal than *à*, or maybe because of some subtle meaning nuance of *de*, when mixed with the meaning of *travailler*, makes it sound unusual)". this question, i suspect, is impossible to answer. i can't help but wonder about it, though; as a French-language learner, *à* and *de* seem so arbitrary/"empty" that it surprises me that one cd sound more formal than the other (ie when both are permitted) !

Comment: *Commencer à travailler* is used also in formal texts too. That's *je commence de travailler* which is very formal, I would even say mannered. Usage is key here. *Commencer de* is never used spontaneously. It can almost only be found in literary texts, often to avoid a *hiatus*.

Comment: Google NGrams shows that [the trend is clearly against *commencer de*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=commencer+de+%2F+commencer+%C3%A0&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 1):

[Le bon usage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage) (10th edition) says:

> Un certain nombre de verbes construisent l'infinitif complément avec *à* ou *de* indifféremment : c'est l'oreille qui décide<sup>1</sup>.

follows a list that includes *s'efforcer*.

So there's no difference in meaning between *s'efforcer à* and *s'efforcer de*. Just go by the ear. There are indeed times when one sounds better than the other.

Here's a case where I would not hesitate using *de* and not *à* because of the two consecutive [a] sounds (*à avancer*):

> Il s'efforçait d'avancer aussi vite que moi mais je marche trop vite pour lui.

I would probably not favour *de* over *à* in front of any vowel sound.

The examples given in *Le bon usage* for *s'efforcer* are:

> - Tandis qu'ils s'efforçaient à trouver des phrases banales (G. Flaubert)
> - Il était gai, elle s'efforçait à l'être. (R. Martin du Gard)
> - Elle s'efforçait en vain à sourire.  (A. Gide)

> - S'efforcer de soulever un fardeau. (Académie)
> - Je vais m'efforcer d'y mettre un peu d'ordre. (F. Mauriac)

In *La préposition: Règles, exercices, corrigés* by Grevisse but 2018 edition revised after his death, it is mentioned that *s'efforcer de* is common and *s'efforcer à* is more literary.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In a footnote Grevisse adds that with *s'efforcer pour* could also be used. He gives only one example. I'll add that this is extremely rare and I would not advise it to someone who doesn't want to create a special effect.</sup>